# Is there a specific method to copy the Yocto Project build images (Kirkstone) into another required directory using Yocto Project variables?

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-kirkstone

Currently, I am building the Kirkstone release-based Yocto Project images. These images are deployed in the `../build/temp/deploy/images/<$MACHINE>/` directory. Now, I need to copy these built images into `../build/<new_directory>` using a Yocto Project script and Yocto Project variables.

Could someone please suggest a script, method, or example for copying Yocto BSP images into `../build/<new_directory>` within this directory?

Answer (score 0):

The variable configured with the destination is `DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE`, to see the current value execute:

`bitbake -e | grep ^DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE`

To create a new path, edit the **conf/local.conf** file and at the end add:

`DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE="<your-new-deploy-destination>"`

Comment: if share some specific example for this variable:  ```DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE="<your-new-deploy-destination>``` it would be great helpful.

Comment: Look at the description in the documentation itself:
[DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/4.0.16/singleindex.html#term-DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE) and [DEPLOY_DIR](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/4.0.16/singleindex.html#term-DEPLOY_DIR)